# yii 1.1 datepicker's language into ajax rendered view

Tags: ajax, yii, datepicker, internationalization

I have written an app with Yii (starting from Gii) where I have the admin view for a model with datepicker filters ([thanks this tutorial](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/318/using-cjuidatepicker-for-cgridview-filter/)).

My language in the main config file is set to "it".

It works fine, BUT if I modify my application for rendering this view after ajax request (first I open a page of my site with the layout, then click on an ajax link to request admin view (without layout)), datepicker's language is set to japanese first time! How can I resolve this?

I have already included this code in my layout file:

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile(Yii::app()->getClientScript()->getCoreScriptUrl() . '/jui/js/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js');
```

Comment: Can you provide your code?

Comment: Try `Yii::app()->clientScript->getCoreScriptUrl()` instead of  `Yii::app()->getClientScript()->getCoreScriptUrl()`

Comment: It doesn't work! I think the problem is that javascript code is not encapsulated into `jQuery(function($) { ... })` if I comment out the line `$this->beginContent('//layouts/main');` in my view